# Removing an item from React-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have created [my own example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-leakey-hfi1bc?file=/src/Container.jsx) off of [this React-dnd example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_js/01-dustbin/multiple-targets?from-embed) to create the drag and drop. I have added a Card which can use onRemove function to remove a card. Even when Im clearing out the state array with all the objects I dont see the removal effect.

My removal function:

```
const handleRemove = useCallback(
(index, item) => {
  // Delete a value if found, all occurrences
  update(dustbins, {
    items: (dustbins) =>
      dustbins && dustbins.filter((arrItem) => arrItem !== item)
  });

  if (dustbins && dustbins.includes(item) && index >= 0) {
    update(dustbins, { lastDroppedItem: { $splice: [[index, 1]] } });
  }

  // Delete at a specific index, no matter what value is in it
  //   update(dustbins, { lastDroppedItem: { $splice: [[index, 1]] } });
},
[dustbins]
  );
```

dustbins received in this method are constantly undefined and not sure why though. which basically doesnt run the rest of the statements in this method. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Another challenge I am facing here is that I can drag and drop an item but this solution creates duplicates. I tried using `$splice` function but that doesnt work as Dustbin.jsx uses  `drop: onDrop,` method to handle drop functionality. How can I remove the duplicates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I finally made it work. So I can answer my own question here.

Im using `immutabilityHelper` function `$set` which is similar to a normal set function.

```
   const indexOf = useCallback(function indexOf(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      console.log("Arr", array[i]);
      if (
        array[i].lastDroppedItem &&
        array[i].lastDroppedItem.name === item.name
      )
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }, []);

  const handleRemove = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      const index = indexOf(dustbins, item);
      console.log("LastDroppedItem Index", index);
      if (index < 0) return;
      setDustbins(
        update(dustbins, {
          [index]: {
            lastDroppedItem: {
              $set: null
            }
          }
        })
      );
```

Im first finding an index and then setting a null on `lastDroppeditem` on that `index`. Hope it helps others. [Link to the working source](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snowflake-dq6ins?file=/src/Container.jsx).